# is it possible to run .exe files from assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to run an assembly code (school project) and I like to use a result of a .exe file (a .bmp image) so I was wondering if it possible to run him from the assembly code so later I will be able to use the .bmp image

I don't know if it even possible but if it is I'll be glad if some one can explain it for me

Comment: I assume you're using x86 asm under Windows, based on the filenames?  If your asm program is linked against a C library, you can use the `system` function to run shell commands.  Otherwise WinAPI CreateProcess or something like that.  TL:DR: yes make a system call to ask the OS to start it.

Comment: You can also do that in C.

Comment: What operating system, architecture, and assembler are you programming for?